# Object Animator Update Listener keep firing like a crazy

Tags: android, listener, objectanimator

Good day.Android object animator is keep firing like crazy nothing helps to stop it!NOTHING! please help me what i have done wrong?

```
    AnimatedColorSpan span = new AnimatedColorSpan(context);
    final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(textToShow);
    this.spannableString = spannableString;
    String substring = textToShow.toLowerCase();
    int start = textToShow.toLowerCase().indexOf(substring);
    int end = start + substring.length();
    spannableString.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);

    objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            span, ANIMATED_COLOR_SPAN_FLOAT_PROPERTY, 0, 100);
    objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new FloatEvaluator());
    objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(updateListener);
    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    objectAnimator.setDuration(DURATION);
    objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    objectAnimator.start();

 private static final Property<AnimatedColorSpan, Float> ANIMATED_COLOR_SPAN_FLOAT_PROPERTY
        = new Property<AnimatedColorSpan, Float>(Float.class, "ANIMATED_COLOR_SPAN_FLOAT_PROPERTY") {
    @Override
    public void set(AnimatedColorSpan span, Float value) {
        span.setTranslateXPercentage(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Float get(AnimatedColorSpan span) {
        return span.getTranslateXPercentage();
    }
};

public static RainbowAnimation get() {
    return rainbowAnimation;
}

public void stopRainbowAnimation() {
    stopCalled = true;
    if (objectAnimator != null) {
        objectAnimator.removeUpdateListener(updateListener);
        objectAnimator.cancel();
        objectAnimator.removeAllListeners();
        objectAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        textViewToAttach.setText(textToShow);
    }
    System.gc();
}


private ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener updateListener = new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        if (!stopCalled) {
            textViewToAttach.setText(spannableString);
        } else {
            if (objectAnimator != null) {
                objectAnimator.setDuration(10);
                objectAnimator.removeUpdateListener(this);
                objectAnimator = null;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I have tried everything here and you can see i am removing everything which is possible to remove but it keeps just logging and it drives me crazy because heaps grows as hell!
What is wrong with my code guys what i have done wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop animator call

```
objectAnimator.end();
```

If you want the animation not to repeat, please comment this line

```
objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
```

It won't repeat the animation again.

Comment: i see the issue is that i want the animation to repeat as long as i disable it manually that is the idea but meanwhile i will try this code definatally see what is going on

Comment: hmm yeah still not working.....animating like crazy